# Entity Framework Core and complex value-object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to model an entity with a complex value object.

The database structure could be something similar to this:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|                car                  |
+----------------------+--------------+
| id                   | CHAR(40)     |
+----------------------+--------------+
| model                | VARCHAR(255) |
+----------------------+--------------+
| specs_engine_version | VARCHAR(255) |
+----------------------+--------------+
| specs_lighting       | VARCHAR(255) |
+----------------------+--------------+


+------------------------------------+
|      specs_interior_equipment      |
+-----------------------+------------+
| car_id                | CHAR(40)   |
+-----------------------+------------+
| interior_equipment_id | INT(11)    |
+-----------------------+------------+
```

This is the `Car` entity:

```
public class Car : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }

    public Specs Specs { get; set; }

    public Car()
    { }
}
```

This is the `Specs` value object:

```
public class Specs : ValueObject<Specs>
{
    public string EngineVersion { get; private set; }
    public string Lighting { get; private set; }
    public List<int> InteriorEquipment { get; private set; }

    public Specs()
    {}
}
```

I'm configuring the mappings more or less like this:

```
class CarMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        builder.ToTable("car");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        builder.OwnsOne(j => j.Specs, l =>
        {
            l.Property(t => t.EngineVersion).HasColumnName("specs_engine_version");
            l.Property(t => t.Lighting).HasColumnName("specs_lighting");
        });
    }
}
```

The question is: how should I configure the mappings in order to persist the interior equipment in a separate table?

I know I can define the interior equipment as an object an use something like this:

```
builder
    .HasMany(j => j.InteriorEquipment)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.CarId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

but I don't know how to join all pieces...

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to keep table splitting by using an object to represent an equipment.

This is the mapping configuration:

```
class CarMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        builder.ToTable("car");

        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("name");

        builder.OwnsOne(j => j.Specs, l =>
        {
            l.Property(t => t.EngineVersion).HasColumnName("specs_engine_version");
            l.Property(t => t.Lighting).HasColumnName("specs_lighting");

            l.OwnsMany(x => x.InteriorEquipment, x =>
            {
                x.HasKey(t => t.Id);

                x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("CarId");

                x.ToTable("specs_interior_equipment");

                x.Property(j => j.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                x.Property(j => j.CategoryId).HasColumnName("equipment_id");
                x.Property(j => j.CarId).HasColumnName("car_id");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the equipment object:

```
public class Equipment: TEntity<Guid>
{


    private Equipment() { }


    public Equipment(Guid carId, int equipmentId)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        CarId = carId;
        EquipomentId = equipmentId;
    }


    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public Guid CarId { get; internal set; }
    public int EquipmentId { get; internal set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Marc

I think in your case you need a separated class to build the table specs, this should be not done in the car class  Something like:

```
class SpecMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Spec>
```

then you can add a function in your repository calls to retrieve all the info.

Here I post you how we resolve this in InfoJobs, hope it helps you.

Class Candidate Points to CandidateResumeDeficiencies, so Candidate could have a list of CandidateResumeDeficiencies.

-> The CandidateResumeClass

public class CandidateResume : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        #region .: Properties :.

```
    public int IdCandidateResume { get; protected set; }
    public int IdCandidate { get; protected set; }
    ....
 }
```

-> The Deficiency class

```
public class CandidateResumeDeficiency
{
    public int IdCandidateResumeDeficiency { get; private set; }
    public int IdCandidateResume { get; private set; }
    public int IdDeficiency1 { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

-> The builder

```
class CandidateEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Candidate>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Candidate> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("candidates",    EFContext.DbSchema.candidate.ToString());

        builder.HasKey(b => b.IdCandidate);
        builder.HasAlternateKey(b => new { b.IdCompany, b.Email });

    }

}

class CandidateResumeDeficiencyEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CandidateResumeDeficiency>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CandidateResumeDeficiency> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("candidateresumedeficiencies", EFContext.DbSchema.candidate.ToString());

        builder.HasKey(b => b.IdCandidateResumeDeficiency);
    }
}
```

-> The Repository

```
 public class CandidateResumeRepository : EFRepository<CandidateResume, int>, ICandidateResumeRepository
{
    public CandidateResumeRepository(EFContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<CandidateResume> GetFullAsync(int idCandidateResume) =>
        await ((EFContext)_dbContext).CandidateResumes

                                              .Include(c => c.Deficiencies)

                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.IdCandidateResume == idCandidateResume);
```

}

Comment: Thank you Xavi, but in my specific scenario I need to share same table for the entity and value object while storing the value object collection in a separate table